# Add Expire to headers doesnt seem to work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have the following code

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
            {
                var headers = ctx.Context.Request.GetTypedHeaders();
                headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
                {
                    MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365)
                };
            }

        });
```

static file in network tab
[image]

localhost doc[image]

Comment: What environment are you running in? In Development things are intentionally *not* cached.

Comment: i was in dev, but told chrome to disable cache, anyways i deployed it to live, it now caches .css and js but NOT images (png/jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a header for the response, not request. Change

```
var headers = ctx.Context.Request.GetTypedHeaders();
```

to

```
var headers = ctx.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders();
```